# Redisson creates an extra key on storing a java POJO

Tags: java, spring-boot, redisson

I'm using redisson (3.11.4) with spring boot (2.1.5) to store java objects.

My POJO looks like this.

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@REntity
public class ParentRecord {

    @RId
    private String id;

    private String type;

    private String root;

    private Map<String, String> children;
}
```

And then I go on to store my data using `merge`.

```
liveObjectService.merge(parentRecord);
messageKeyCache.put(parentRecord.getId(), parentRecord.getId(), 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Once I merge I see two keys one is the actual data.
`redisson_live_object:{223334343322}:com.memorystore.schema.ParentRecord:id:java.lang.String`
and the other is `redisson_live_object_field:{223334343322}:com.memorystore.schema.ParentRecord:children:org.redisson.RedissonMap`

I can delete the first key by doing `liveObjectService.delete(ParentRecord.class, someId);`
but that doesn't delete the second key. Shouldn't it be deleted when I delete the first key? If not then how do I delete it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Add @RCascade annotation:

```
@RCascade(RCascadeType.ALL)
private Map<String, String> children;
```

2) Delete object:

```
public void deleteByKey(K key) {
    T object = findByKey(key);
    liveObjectService.delete(object);
}

private T findByKey(K key) {
    return liveObjectService.get(type, key);
}
```

where type - some class(ParentRecord.class).

Comment: Could you please properly format your answer? It will help in understanding it better.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you for your answer.